# How to declare a variable inside an Oracle select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Oracle SQL request:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       DECODE(
                 SUM(CASE WHEN col3='A' AND col4='+' THEN col5 ELSE 0 END),
                 NULL,
                 0,
                 SUM(CASE WHEN col3='A' AND col4='+' THEN col5 ELSE 0 END)
             )
FROM mytable
group by col1, col2;
```

I am asking if there is a way to declare a kind of variable and have something like this:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       DECODE(
                 myVariable,
                 NULL,
                 0,
                 myVariable
             )
FROM mytable
group by col1, col2;
```

Comment: How are you intending to use this query? Variables are not a SQL thing  but belong to the realm of the software which runs the query. So the solution will depend on whether your want to run the query interactively in some client such as SQL\*Plus, as part of a parameterised stored procedure or as a JDBC PreparedStatement (to name just three possibilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, but you could do a subquery:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       DECODE(
                 SUM(myColumn),
                 NULL,
                 0,
                 SUM(myColumn)
             )
FROM (
    SELECT 
        col1,
        col2,
        CASE WHEN col3='A' AND col4='+' THEN col5 ELSE 0 END myColumn   
        FROM mytable
     ) a
group by col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simlpy use `coalesce()` (or `nvl()`) instead of `decode()`.

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       coalesce(sum(CASE
                      WHEN col3 = 'A'
                           AND col4 = '+' THEN
                        col5
                      ELSE
                        0
                    END),
                0)
       FROM mytable
       GROUP BY col1,
                col2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()`.  I think this is sufficient:

```
select col1, col2,
       coalesce(sum(case when col3 = 'A' and col4 = '+' then col5 end), 0)
from mytable
group by col1, col2;
```

In actual fact, this expression:

```
sum(case when col3 = 'A' and col4 = '+' then col5 else 0 end)
```

Cannot return `NULL` in a query with a `group by` -- every group has at least one row and the `else` guarantees a `0` returns rather than `NULL`.

So, this should also do what you want:

```
select col1, col2,
       sum(case when col3 = 'A' and col4 = '+' then col5 end)
from mytable
group by col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use substitution variables:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       DECODE(
                 &&myVariable,
                 NULL,
                 0,
                 &&myVariable
             )
FROM mytable
group by col1, col2;
```

More info here [Oracle SQL*Plus Substitution Variables](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables)

Comment: I believe the intent is to treat `SUM(CASE WHEN col3='A' AND col4='+' THEN col5 ELSE 0 END)` as a "variable" so it does not need to be repeated, not to pass in arbitrary amounts as variables,